# How to push data from asp.net to flash/silverlight client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flash, asp.net-ajax, flash-cs3

I'm developing chat application. I use flash as front end and asp.net back-end. My question is: can my asp.net web app send data to flash app in browser without post back ?actually it mean asp.net push data to flash client. I don't know much about flash or siverlight, dose flash support to do that ? or other way help me connect direct from server to browser without using post back or Jabber ? Please give me your advise, thanks so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another option for you written by people at Microsoft:

http://laharsub.codeplex.com/

We use it and so far so good. Very fast.

Comment: Oh, Greate! I'm checking on it, dose it replace IIS ? Can asp.net MVC host on this server ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the 100% solution, called Diffusion sever:
http://demo.pushtechnology.com/docs/manual/apis/flash/index.html

Answer (score 0):

No, the server cannot push data to the client without postback. It's the client application that needs to fetch it from the server. In fact there's the [WebSocket API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) draft in HTML5 that allows the server to push data to the client but it still has limited browser support and you will need a server that is capable of handling this protocol.

So currently the only reliable way of doing this is by having the client poll the server for data.

Comment: Since DucN asks about a Flash based client, Flash actually has had a socket API for 10 years now, since Flash Player 5 back in 2000.

Comment: @Lars, yes, I know that Flash has a socket API, but he is asking about the server pushing data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Flash has support for socket communication, that can be used to push data to the client without polling.

You mention asp.net, I'm no expert in that area, but maybe the "Active Server Pages" aspect doesn't fit so well with socket communication, but I'm pretty sure you can build the server side of a chat, pushing data via sockets, in .Net.

Comment: what are you talking about? This sentence makes no sense: `Flash has support for socket communication, that can be used to push data to the client without polling`. Flash is **the client** :-) Think of it as an enhanced javascript.

Comment: Yes, of course Flash is for the client. What I'm saying is that, since a client in Flash can receive data via socket communication, it is fully possible to build a chat service using Flash as the client, provided you have a server that can send the data.

Comment: I heard that Flash has socket API to open port and send data through that port, But in my case, server is not an desktop application, it's asp.net website which is hosted in IIS webserver, and IIS just open only 1 port for my website (default port is 80). I don't know how can I talk to flash client through its socket. Lars, could you explain more detail for me, or do have any tutorial about it ? I think that socket in flash client just use for flash media server or red5, not IIS, am I right ?