# How to receive data continuously from asp.net server into flash?

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to receive XML data continuously like stream download from server to flash , is it possible?
i call response flush in asp.net every second while printing data and i want flash to receive data every second but not to close the connection after receiving data.
for example i have this file on server (you can check) :

```
http://5.9.121.41/handler.ashx
```

What method can i use on flash?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to set up a socket server to push data to Flash as it is received. This way the server can continually notify Flash as new data is ready, which could be every second. Reference this q/a for more details:

[How to push data from asp.net to flash/silverlight client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213511/how-to-push-data-from-asp-net-to-flash-silverlight-client)